# AngularJS $http GET request returning 404 though corresponding Java method is executed

Tags: angularjs, spring

Firing AngularJS Rest URL as a GET request from AngularJS, its 
returning 404    though its hitting the required method on server 
side (spring implementation) and producing the desired Result

Below is the method firing the angularjs request

```
   getCredentials : function(){
          return $http.get('/helloRest/getUsername');
     }
```

The above method results in the below URL

URL : http://localhost:8083/helloRest/getUsername

below is the stack traces

```
<body>
 <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /helloRest/getUsername</h1>
 <div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p>
 <b>message</b> 
 <u>/helloRest/getUsername</u></p><p>
 <b>description</b> 
 <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p>
 <hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.37</h3></body></html>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <web-app>

    <filter>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
     </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
         </servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> 

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Below is test-server.xml(dispatcher servlet)

```
   <beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.simpro"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.org.simpro"></jpa:repositories>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    </bean>

    <bean id="HelloWorldRestController" class="com.org.simpro.controller.HelloWorldRestController">
        <property name="userService" ref="userServiceImpl"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id= "userServiceImpl" class="com.org.simpro.service.UserServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="HR"/>
        <property name="password" value="hr"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.org.simpro.model" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <!-- 
                <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>

                //jpa hibernate properties
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
                hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
                hibernate.show_sql=false
                -->
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>   
            </props>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <import resource="security-context.xml"/> 

</beans>
```

Below is the security-context.xml

```
  <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">


        <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/authenticate"  
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>   


        <security:intercept-url  pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:intercept-url  pattern="/authenticate" access="ROLE_USER"/>

        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager>
              <security:authentication-provider>
                <security:user-service>
                  <security:user name="user" password="password" 
                      authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
                </security:user-service>
              </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>  
</beans>
```

Below is the method which the URL is hitting

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getUsername",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public void authenticateUser(HttpServletRequest hreq){
        System.out.println("credentials are");
        Principal principalObject = (Principal)              SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        System.out.println("security"+principalObject.toString());

  }
```

The AngularJS $http request is returning me 404,though the above java 
         method is executing successfully.  I should get 200 instead of 404
         as the server response, Could you kindly check this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/helloRest")
public class HelloWorldRestController {


public UserService getUserService() {
    return userService;
}


public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/getUsername",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void authenticateUser(){
    System.out.println("credentials are");
    Principal principalObject =(Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    System.out.println("security"+principalObject.toString());


}

@Autowired
UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work



@RequestMapping(value = "/pullusers/", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<User_ex>> listAllUser_exs() {
    Iterable<User_ex> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    System.out.println(users.toString());
    //return null;
    /*if(users.isEmpty()){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }*/
    return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<User_ex>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}


//-------------------Retrieve Single User--------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User_ex> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
    User_ex user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}



//-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/persistuser/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User_ex user,    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());

    if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
        System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getName() + " already exist");
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    userService.saveUser(user);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}


//-------------------check if particular user exists or not----------------------------------------------------------
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate", method=RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User_ex> isCurrentUserExists(String username, String password){
    System.out.println("A User with name " + username +password+ "exist");
    User_ex user = userService.isUserLoginExist(username,password);
    if(user != null){
        return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(user,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return null;
}




//------------------- Update a User --------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/updateuser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<User_ex> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User_ex user) {
    System.out.println("Updating User " + id);

    User_ex currentUser = userService.findById(id);

    if (currentUser==null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    currentUser.setName(user.getName());
    currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
    currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());

    userService.updateUser(currentUser);
    return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}

//------------------- Delete a User --------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/removeuser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<User_ex> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);

    User_ex user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    userService.deleteUserById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}


//------------------- Delete All Users --------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/removeusers/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<User_ex> deleteAllUsers() {
    System.out.println("Deleting All Users");

    userService.deleteAllUsers();
    return new ResponseEntity<User_ex>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

}

Comment: @JB Nizet, this is yesterday's same question could you please look at it

Comment: can you add the controller?

Comment: @kuhajeyan, thanks for responding , I am not able to post the angularjs conttoller code its long I am not able to submit it ......

Comment: your spring controller

Comment: @kuhajeyan , added spring controller, name with url mapping (.getUsername) not called and giving 404 Thanks you

Comment: what do you expect as response ?

Comment: @kuhajeyan,only 200 code on the angularjs side

Comment: the method should execute and a 200 response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getUsername",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity authenticateUser(){
    System.out.println("credentials are");
    Principal principalObject =(Principal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    System.out.println("security"+principalObject.toString());

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);


}
```

Comment: tried the above snippet, result is URL is not hitting this method and 404 response

Comment: return $http.get('http://localhost:8083/simpro1/helloRest/getUsername');

Comment: getting a class cast exception , the method is called i need to fix the class cast and then I will check

Answer (score 0):

Blindly guessing :

1. Your configuration is :

   `<context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>`

   But you gave the *dispatcher servlet*' name as `test-server.xml` while    it should be `test-servlet.xml`
2. The controller class is not being put under the `com.org.simpro`
3. One (or both) of those `security-context.xml` and `test-servlet.xml` is not being put under the *WEB-INF*.
4. Check your *maven* config. (*pom.xml*) whether or not the following dependencies exist :

   ```
     <!-- Spring Security -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
       <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
       <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
5. I don't see how you load your secuty config via (in your *web.xml*) :

   ```
    <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
   <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
       </param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
6. It's possibly normal behavior since there's no view resolver configured in your *dispatcher servlet*, check your server's console instead to check the output for the *getUsername*.

Well, too many things to guess...

Comment: You didn't even take the time to clarify which one you want to notify, lol.

Comment: @ Jan Kaufmann, I so am sorry Jan , please forgive me , thanks a ton, I regret it what i have done